# Fetching the results of sys_Refcurson in Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a function which uses sys_Refcursor

```
create or replace function get_employee
  (p_loc in number)
  return sys_refcursor
as  
 l_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc
   for select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.department_name 
     from employees a, 
          departments b 
    where a.department_id=b.department_id 
      and location_id=p_loc;

 return l_rc; 
end;
```

and running this in SQL developer

```
select (get_employee(5)) from dual;
```

In Java I used

```
strSql+="select (get_employee(5)) from dual";

        resultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery(strSql);


        while (resultSet.next()) {



            System.out.println("here is the " + resultSet.getString(1) );
            System.out.println("here is the " + resultSet.getString(2) );


        }
```

But the above code is returning the resultset as Null.

Could you please tell me the ways we can retrieve the result values of that function in Java?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to execuse query to get ref cusros.

```
create or replace function get_refcursor
return sys_refcursor
is
 c sys_refcursor;
begin
  open c for select 1 x from dual;
  return c;
end;


    DriverManager.registerDriver ( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:1521:***","***","***");

    OracleCallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call get_refcursor }"); ;
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cstmt.execute();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1);
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println('Result: '+rs.getBigDecimal(1));
    }
    rs.close();
    cstmt.close();

Result: 1
```

Comment: Also Dmitry.. is it possible to get the resultset based on its name? like for eg: rs.getString("FirstName")

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use column name in getter methods of ResultSet, please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal(java.lang.String)